# What are the differences among `next(f)`, `f.readline()` and `f.next()` in Python?

Tags: python, readfile

I process one file: skip the header (comment), process the first line, process other lines.

```
f = open(filename, 'r')

# skip the header
next(f)  

# handle the first line
line =  next(f)  
process_first_line(line)

# handle other lines
for line in f:
    process_line(line)
```

If `line = next(f)` is replaced with `line = f.readline()`, it will encounter the error.

> ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Therefore, I would like to know the differences among `next(f)`, `f.readline()` and `f.next()` in Python?

Comment: The `next(iter)` function calls `iter.next()`, and will handle the `StopIteration` exception if you give `next()` a second argument. See the dupe for details on `next()` versus `file.readline()`.

Comment: The duplicate covers the same idea, which is the inconsistency resulting from using both `readline` and `next`. However, this post specifically asks what the "difference" is between the two, which differs from what the dup is asking. Someone else asking the same question will likely find this post instead of the dup. In addition, the accepted answer doesn't really answer the question, as it doesn't explain what `readline` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next),

> A `file` object is its own iterator, for example `iter(f)` returns `f` (unless f is closed). When a file is used as an iterator, typically in a `for` loop (for example, `for line in f: print line.strip()`), the `next()` method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or raises `StopIteration` when EOF is hit when the file is open for reading (behavior is undefined when the file is open for writing). **In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the `next()` method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining `next()` with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right.**

Basically, when the `next` function is called on a Python's file object, it fetches a certain number of bytes from the file and processes them and returns only the current line (end of current line is determined by the newline character). So, the file pointer is moved. It will not be at the same position where the current returned line ends. So, calling `readline` on it will give inconsistent result. That is why mixing both of them are not allowed.

Comment: While it addresses the error the OP was encountering, this doesn't really answer the question as stated. It only explains how `next()` works, and not the other functions.